# DraggableScrollableNotification + snap + setState

Tags: flutter, dart

Using DraggableScrollableNotification + DraggableScrollableSheet with `snap` property set as true, in the `onNotification` event, causes that the DraggableScrollableSheet does not work properly.

```
void _update(double extent) {
    double _scrollPosition = extent;

    setState(() {
      newBorderRadiusSize =
          ((minChildSize * defaulBorderRadiusSize) / _scrollPosition);

      newHorizontalPadding =
          ((horizontalPadding * minChildSize) / _scrollPosition);
      newVerticalPadding = ((verticalPadding * minChildSize) / _scrollPosition);

      //does not look smooth :/
      if (extent >= maxChildSize) {
        newBorderRadiusSize = 0;
        newHorizontalPadding = 0;
        newVerticalPadding = 0;
      }
    });
  }

return NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        _update(notification.extent);
        return true;
      },
      child: Positioned.fill(
        left: newHorizontalPadding,
        right: newHorizontalPadding,
        bottom: newVerticalPadding,
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          maxChildSize: maxChildSize,
          minChildSize: minChildSize,
          initialChildSize: minChildSize,
          controller: _draggableScrollableController,
          snap: true,
          builder: ((context, scrollController) {
            
            return ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(newBorderRadiusSize),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: AppColors.secondary),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TaxiDragger(),
                      Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                      TaxiNotification(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

if i remove the `snap` property (which as default is set as false) everything works perfectly, however i would like to have snap property

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered something really interesting: if you modify the state variable within the onNotification function without actually using `setState` — it works exactly as expected

```
  class _MyStatefullWidgetState extends State<MyStatefullWidget> {
      bool shouldDisplaySomething = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) => NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
          onNotification: (DraggableScrollableNotification event) {
              // doing this in setState breaks DraggableScrollableSheet behaviour
              shouldDisplaySomething = event.extent > 0.9;
              return false;
          },
          child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
              ...
```

It seems that DraggableScrollableSheet causes the child to rerender when it's being dragged and the new rendering cycles will pick up the updated state even though setState was not explicitly used

It might also be important to return false from the onNotification function, since that bool determines notification bubbling — if you return true the bubbling will be stopped which in turn will mess with the default intended behaviour

Comment: i will test it, i found that in the flutter master branch, the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

answering to my own question, seems that its a bug with flutter, in any case i was able to archive what i was looking for, instead of animate the Positioned, im animating the Container inside the DraggableScrollable.

```
return Positioned.fill(
      child: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
        onNotification: (notification) {
          _scrolledSize = notification.extent;

          newBorderRadiusSize =
              ((minChildSize * defaulBorderRadiusSize) / _scrolledSize);

          newHorizontalPadding =
              ((horizontalPadding * minChildSize) / _scrolledSize);
          newVerticalPadding =
              ((verticalPadding * minChildSize) / _scrolledSize);

          //does not look smooth :/
          if (_scrolledSize >= maxChildSize) {
            newBorderRadiusSize = 0;
            newHorizontalPadding = 0;
            newVerticalPadding = 0;
          }

          return true;
        },
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          maxChildSize: maxChildSize,
          minChildSize: minChildSize,
          initialChildSize: minChildSize,
          controller: _draggableScrollableController,
          snap: true,
          builder: ((context, scrollController) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppColors.secondary,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(newBorderRadiusSize)),
              //width: newBorderRadiusSize,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: newHorizontalPadding,
                right: newHorizontalPadding,
                bottom: newVerticalPadding,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: CustomScrollView(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: scrollController,
                slivers: [
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (context, i) => Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(newHorizontalPadding.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: newHorizontalPadding)),
                          TaxiDragger(),
                          Divider(color: Colors.transparent),
                          TaxiNotification(),
                        ],
                      ),
                      childCount: 20,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

i hope this help others.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned by [Nikita Eroshin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11676468/nikita-eroshin), either one works, but not both at the same time.

You can use snap: true together with setState if you get rid of DraggableScrollableNotification listener and use controller listener instead:

```
  ...
  DraggableScrollableController controller = DraggableScrollableController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.size > 0.2) {
        setState(() {
          // Your logic here
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          // Your logic here
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  ...

  ...
  DraggableScrollableSheet(
      controller: controller,
      snap: true,
      snapSizes: const [0.1, 0.9],
  ...
```